# SOLARIS - verify OS version before OS upgarde

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, solaris, uname

I have SOLARIS 10 OS

SOLARIS OS was upgrade to new version as the following version - 144488-02

Example of OS version verification:

```
   uname -v
   Generic_144488-02
```

.

```
   uname -a
   SunOS star1a 5.10 Generic_144488-02 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T5220
```

.

```
   cat /etc/release 
                   Solaris 10 5/09 s10s_u7wos_08 SPARC
       Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                    Use is subject to license terms.
                         Assembled 30 March 2009
```

How I can identify the SOLARIS version before OS upgrade?

I mean before the upgrade  –  uname –v show different version ,

but with which command or file I can find this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try the

cat /etc/release

maybe that can give you an answer.

or uname -a

Comment: Looks like cat /etc/release gave you the answer, right? 5/09 is the version. Check [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history[/link]

Comment: NO /etc/release not have the old version !!! , and uname -a give  the same version -:(

Comment: Ok, you want to know what version solaris was before the upgrade, right? Maybe get /etc/release from a backup?

Comment: /etc/release not give any data about the previos SOLARIS version